# JSF Confirmation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My application looks and works great so far. My users will have a lot of crucial decisions to make, like deleting or editing entities or accepting applications which causes an email. For that reason I want to integrate a common form of confirmation. And that's why I ask you:

**What's your favourite way of confirmation** (infobox, confirmation page etc..) **and how to implement it properly?**

I am looking forward to your ideas :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will vote for a dialog:

you can user friendly [PrimeFaces dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

Comment: nice, there is a special one for confirmation: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf

Answer (score 1):

- The simplest way would be to use javascript: `confirm("Are you sure?")`
- A more stylable way would be to use [`<rich:modalPanel>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html) with Yes/No, which in turn would submit the form. [See an example](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/max_katz/2008/11/richfaces_confirmation_dialog)